# Android - Activity as Dialog with ActionBar

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-dialog

I am trying to reuse one of the activity as a dialog by setting the **Theme** to **Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog**. But I am not able to display ActionBar for that dialog. When I try to enable ActionBar by using requestWindowFeature(), it throws an exception **"java.lang.IllegalStateException: ActionBarImpl can only be used with a compatible window decor layout"**

I need to have an ActionBar with menu items in the dialog.

Comment: what is the need for a dialog theme if you want action bar in activity?

Comment: I am developing app for both phone and tablet. On phone I am using it as a normal activity with ActionBar, but for tablet I need to show it as a dialog with ActionBar. That ActionBar will contain Title and Menu items.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/Y5wnstMT5Lo/upOijj1OOJIJ. check this if it helps

Comment: I am doing exactly that. I tried to set requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR) in onCreate() method before setContentView(), but it is throwing the above exception.

Comment: @Vivek did you find a solution for your problem? I am also stuck on the same exception.